# Issue in Rest Service with JSON input in websphere

Tags: json, rest, websphere, resteasy, using

I am trying to develop a rest service using JBOSS RestEasy which will support both JSON and XML. In order to implement that I am using the below mentioned jars. I am deploying the application in JBoss server in my local and for SIT environment I am deploying it in WebSphere server.

Now, my service is running successfully in my local Jboss environment using both JSON and XML input but in WebSphere environment I am facing below issue with JSON input. Please check my changes below and let me know is there any changes or any jar i need to add to make it work in websphere server.

Issue:

> ErrorInternal Server Error
>       status is Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [Resteasy]: filter is unavailable

JARs Used:

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

Service Class:

```
@POST
    @Path("/getTravelIdByEmail")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response getTravelDetail(TravelerIDByEmailReq Req, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {

        MediaType type = headers.getMediaType();
        StringWriter hotelRespXml = new StringWriter();
        TravelInfo info = null;
        TravelerIDByEmailRes response = new TravelerIDByEmailRes();
        ResponseStatus status = new ResponseStatus();
                    status.setStatusCode("00");
                    status.setStatusDescription("SUCCESS");
                    TravelerIdDetails traveleridDetails = new TravelerIdDetails();
                    traveleridDetails.setTravelerID("Set Travle Id");
                    traveleridDetails.setTravelerType("XYZ");
                    response.setTravelerIdDetails(traveleridDetails);
                    response.setResponseStatus(status);
return Response.status(200).type(type).entity(response).build();
```

Any solution would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: Liberty or traditional? Which version?

Comment: we are using IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND, 7.0.0.37

Comment: you need to provide the mentioned jars to WebSphere either via the war's WEB-INF/lib, or MANIFEST.MF or via a shared library.